Is it possible to auto-scroll MUI X Date Range picker when value changes?
Is it possible to have the StaticDateRangePicker from MUI X to auto-scroll to the selected range when the value prop changes?
If the complete range does not fit into the view, scroll the the end-date of the selected range.
Went through the docs and the only prop that seemed related was rangePosition but it didn't help.

HI, Did you see this? https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/4642

I didn't, thanks for sharing. Although it seems a different issue.
